# Taylor series expansion. Is my answer correct?

Tags: taylor-expansion

Is my answer correct?

**Problem:**
What is the largest number $r>0$ for which there are constants $c_n\in \mathbb{C}$, $n = 0,1,2,...$ such that $$\frac{(z^2+\pi^2)(e^z-1)}{\sinh(z)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nz^n$$ for $|z|<r$?

**Solution:**
As I understand it, the question is equivalent to looking for the ball with the largest radius where $f(z)=\frac{(z^2+\pi^2)(e^z-1)}{\sinh(z)}$ has a Taylor series expansion and this is looking for the disk with the largest radius that does not contain any singularity of $f(z)$.

Clearly the possible singularities of $f(z)$ are the zeros of $\sinh(z)$ and since $\sinh(z)=\frac{e^z-e^{-z}}{z}$ should check where $e^z=e^{-z}$ and this happens precisely for $z=\frac{in\pi}{2}$ with $n=0,\pm1,\pm2,...$

The $0$ is an avoidable singularity of $f(z)$ and therefore can be holomorphicly extended at that point. However, $\frac{i\pi}{2}$ is a pole for $f(z)$ and it is of the $\frac{in\pi}{2}$ 2 that has the lowest modulus, so this would be the $r$ sought, that is, for $|z|<\frac{i\pi}{2}$, $f(z)$ has a expansion in Taylor series around $0$.

Comment: You say $|z|<\frac{i\pi}{2}$ but you mean $|z|<\frac{\pi}{2}$.